# Stop site.css overriding table style

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

In my ASP.NET's MVC application, table style in `site.css` file is defined as:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin-top: 1em;
    border: 0 none;
}
```

When I'm creating a table and setting explicitly the border property in my HTML, this style in css is overriding the border property. Result is I'm not able to see borders in my table. This is my table variable:

```
tableT = '<table border="1" style="float:center" id="itemList"><thead><tr><td></td><td>Total</td><td>Completed</td><td>Inprogress</td><td>Pending</td></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table>',
```

I want a table with borders, I don't want to change `site.css` as everywhere else that is being used.

Comment: why don't you just create a .table-border rule in site.css and apply it on the table that needs border?

Comment: When shall be the css style applied to a table and when not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using an inline style with an `!important` rule:

```
<table border="1" style="float:center; border: 1px solid !important;" id="itemList">
```

However, this is quite a messy hack, and [Germain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3165207/germain)'s answer from the comments would be a more elegant solution - it depends if you are able/inclined to edit your CSS file.